# Query to find the Intersection coordinates of multiple Polyon

Tags: postgis, intersection, aggregation

I am using the query below to find out the intersection coordinates of 2 Polygons and it's working fine, but how can I use or modify the query to find the intersection area coordinates for multiple (or N number of) polygons?

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
        ST_INTERSECTION(
                       ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((1.25 9.5,1.375 18.25,7.25 17.875,7.375 9.5,1.25 9.5))'),
                       ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((1.25 9.5,1.375 18.25,7.25 17.875,7.375 9.5,1.25 9.5))')
                )
        );
```

What other alternative do I have?

Answer (score 6):

As katahdin wrote, [ST_Intersection](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Intersection.html)  works only with two geometries. I don't know a variant of it what works on arrays.
If you have your geometries in one table, you can write a function that will do the job, like this:

```
create or replace function ST_IntersectionArray(geoms geometry[]) returns geometry as $$
declare
   i integer;
   tmpGeom geometry;
begin
    tmpGeom := geoms[1];
    FOR i IN 1..array_length(geoms,1) LOOP
      tmpGeom:= ST_Intersection(tmpGeom,geoms[i]);
    END LOOP;
    return tmpGeom;
end;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Example call:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_IntersectionArray(ARRAY(select geom from test_geom)));
```

Answer (score 1):

If your polygons are in two separate tables, say poly1, and poly2, then

```
SELECT As_Text(St_Intersection(poly1.geom, poly2.geom))
FROM poly1, poly2;
```

If all the polygons are in one table, polys, then, assuming you have a primary key 'id':

```
SELECT As_Text(ST_Intersection(p1.geom, p2.geom))
FROM polys AS p1, polys AS p2
WHERE p1.id <> p2.id
```

Comment: `p1.id <> p2.id` will get you doubles: (a,b) and (b,a). It's better to use `>` or `<` instead of `<>`

Answer (score 1):

The ST_Intersect function works with only two geometries at a time. It is a binary relation only.